# Cannot copy mirror some bones between keyframes

Tags: bones, keyframes, mirror

I'm working on an 8 frame walk cycle, and I'd like to copy and mirror the poses of the first 4 frames to the last 4 frames. However, for some reason my arms won't copy mirror properly.

Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Here's a link to my blender file:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50223

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your arm bones are not well oriented:

- In *Edit* mode, select the right upper and lower arm.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> *180* to make a 180° rotation

now it works

[image]